# Balls into bins: probability that first $k-1$ bins contain $2$ balls and $k^{th}$ at least $(t-2)$ balls?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

> We want to throw $n$ balls into $n$ bins uniformly and independently.
>   Given these $n$ bins an order, what's the probability such that first $(k-1)$ bins contain $2$ balls and $k^{th}$ at least $(t-2)$ balls?

---

**My attempt**:

Let $A$ denotes the event such that first $(k-1)$ bins contains  $2$ balls.

Let $B$ denote the event such that $n^{th}$ bin contains at least $(t-2)$ balls.

Then  $P(A)={n \choose 2}(1-\frac{k-1}{n})^{n-2}(\frac{k-1}{n})^2$ and $P(B|A)$ is less than ${n-2 \choose t-2}(\frac{1}{n})^{t-2}$ by union bound.

$$P(A \cap B ) = P(A)P(B|A)\leq {n \choose 2}(1-\frac{k-1}{n})^{n-2}(\frac{k-1}{n})^2{n-2 \choose t-2}(\frac{1}{n})^{t-2}$$

but its looks quite weird, am I correct?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Klangen wait I am updating